# c# copy jpg in clipboard from file Path without convert it to bitmap

Tags: c#

I want to copy a .jpg image in a clipboard and i don't want to convert it in a bitmap because user will paste it in word and bit map loose different infos of images.

Do you know if there is a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular case (you have some file of the filesystem and want to copy it to clipboard and later paste to Word), the following should work

```
var list = new StringCollection();
list.Add(@"path_to_your_file.jpeg");
Clipboard.SetFileDropList(list);
```

It will kind of imitate copying file (ctrl+C) in windows explorer.

Answer (score 2):

This one works fine for me:

```
Clipboard.SetImage(Image.FromFile(@"path_to.jpg"));
```

or if you have your image as byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"path_to.jpg");
Image img;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    img = Image.FromStream(ms);
Clipboard.SetImage(img);
```